# Order the members of a set in MDX

Tags: sql, ssas, mdx, pivot-table, olap

I created the following named set in SSAS :

[image]

When I connect to `SSAS cube` via excel and I retrieve data for this `set` ,
i get different order of the `members`. Is that possible to retrieve the `members` of the set in the same order as created?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Please refer to this answer by the excellent Chris Webb. It should tell you all you need to know.

[Ordering Of Named Sets In Excel](http://blog.crossjoin.co.uk/2013/07/31/ordering-of-named-sets-in-excel/)

Hope that helps,

Ash

Comment: Thank you ... I spend yesterday a lot searching for an MDX Solution , when the trick was in Excel!

Comment: If you have this issue in SSRS (named set not ordering), make sure you don't have an explicit order by in your group